# Cannot react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"

Tags: react-native

I want to try React Native. But so far cannot even start. I have tried for many times.

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"
Scanning folders for symlinks in 
/Users/XXX/Documents/projects/TryReact/node_modules (23ms)
15:38:49: Starting packager...
15:39:01: Starting simulator...
15:39:01: Failed to start simulator:

Error: Command failed: osascript -e tell app "System Events" to count processes whose name is "Simulator"
```

Comment: Did you set your Xcode Command line tools. 
If not,
Open your xcode -> Preferences -> Locations - > Command Line tools

Select xcode version and save

And try to run app again.

Comment: @Chetan I have. Command Line Tools version: Xcode 9.3

Answer (score 4):

You can run :

```
$ instruments -s devices
iPhone 7 (11.3) [5AB4ADC9-BC69-41A2-****] (Simulator)
iPhone 7 (11.3) + Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm (4.3) [1FF656CF-E842-4706-8A66-****] (Simulator)
iPhone 7 Plus (11.3) [1E96A1A2-4919-4302-AA93-****] (Simulator)
iPhone 7 Plus (11.3) + Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm (4.3) [0725657D-535E-419D-B996-****] (Simulator)
```

Then you can run the iPhone7 independent:

```
$ xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 7 (11.3) [5AB4ADC9-BC69-41A2-****]"
```

So you `react-native run-ios` will open the iPhone7.

Same way on iPhone8 iPhoneX iPhone6 iPhoneSE ..

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a device with the specific name "iPhone 7". Open Xcode, Window/Devices and Simulators. Select the Simulators tab and click the + at the bottom left of the screen (not the + in the Paired Watches section). Add the device "iPhone 7", then run the command again: `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"`